# Compile error: expected list separator vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a compile error when running a vba macro. The error is on line:

```
 If inStr(";" & Trim(str(r)) & ";") < 1 Then
```

variables:

```
 Dim str() As String 'string array
 Dim r As Long '
```

Code:

```
 For Each workcell In Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns(4)) 'Go down the   
 cells in Column D
 If InStr(workcell.Value, ";") > 0 Then 'split
 str = Split(workcell.Value, ";")
 For r = LBound(str) To UBound(str)
 If inStr(";" & Trim(str(r)) & ";") < 1 Then
 if instr(";" & trim(str(r)) & ";") = 0 then
 output = output & Trim(str(r)) & ";" 'Add the number and ";" to the end of the string
 End If
 Next r
 Erase str 'Tidy up array, ready to recycle
 End If
```

Comment: If **what** substring is within **what** string? Please read the docs for [instr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function).

Comment: inStr takes at least 2 arguments (comma separated) and you only have 1. Hence "expected list separator" error.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code snippet can you please advise alternatives for what I could use to perform same task?

Comment: Why would you need an alternative? You just need to use the function correctly.

Comment: In third line of your code, you use `InStr` correctly, giving 2 parameters. However, inside your loop, you pass only one parameter.

Comment: I have now changed to: If InStr(workcell.Value, ";" & Trim(str(r)) & ";") < 1 Then

Comment: compile error: invalid next control variable reference

Comment: you are missing an End If and your Next workcell but also, you should specify the start position of InStr e.g. InStr(1, ";" & Trim(Str(r)) & ";") < 1  but why are you adding ; to str(r) ? The logic of these bits seems off especially as the first If inStr(";" & Trim(str(r)) & ";") < 1 won't do anything you can't achieve with the next Instr

Comment: Indent your code, then you can see that you totally mixed your if- and for-statements

Comment: Its ok now thanks everyone:)

Comment: `If inStr(output, ";" & Trim(str(r)) & ";") < 1 Then`  :P